# How to correctly escape query variables to be used in WP_Query

Tags: escaping, query-variable

I've got custom query variables that are added via `query_vars`. For example, 'industry'.

In `pre_get_posts` action I construct and add taxonomy query if there is a value for the 'industry' parameter, like so:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_posts');
function alter_posts( $q ) {
    $tax_query = array();

    // industry taxonomy
    if ( get_query_var( 'industry' ) ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $my_taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => get_query_var( 'industry' )
        );
    }

    // set all previously determined values to the query
    $q->set( "tax_query", $tax_query );
}
```

How do I correctly escape query variable that I get via `get_query_var( 'industry' )`?

Do I use [esc_sql](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql) function, like so `esc_sql( get_query_var( 'industry' ) )` ? What's the correct way to handle the escaping of query variables?

Many thanks,
Dasha

Comment: What do you want to escape? On what basis? As I understand it, the value for your tax query is already given as query var, which you now want to use for the tax query. Are you talking about validation? I don't see any escaping needs here...

Comment: @tf, I'd like to escape custom query variables, but not sure what's the right way to do it. As far as I understand `get_query_var ` doesn't escape the value that it gets from `$wp_query` that in turn came from a URL. And because it's originally from URL, it needs escaping. I'm a bit confused to be honest.

Comment: `get_query_var` doesn't escape data, but `WP_Query` does before performing the database query. However, if you want, you can use the php [`filter_var`](http://it1.php.net/filter_var) function with a proper [filter constant](http://it1.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), like: `filter_var( get_query_var( 'industry' ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );`

Comment: While I agree with @G.M., I don't think you have to worry about escaping anything in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, @G.M. and @MikeNGarrett. I was thinking that `WP_Query` should handle this as I'm using it instead of my custom SQL. Just got a bit confused. I think I'm not gonna worry and leave it up to `WP_Query` to handle it. Thanks for advice!

Comment: How do I close this question? Do I need to add an explicit answer for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function for the `pre_get_posts` action uses a WP_Query object (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

> When using functions such as get_posts or classes such as **WP_Query** and WP_User_Query, **WordPress takes care of the necessary sanitization** in querying the database. However, when retrieving data from a custom table, or otherwise performing a direct SQL query on the database – proper sanitization is then up to you.
>
> -- [Code Tuts+: Data Sanitization and Validation With WordPress](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress--wp-25536)

So in this case, you do not have to escape the query vars.